# Update query using a field from another Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to update Table1.Field1 in Database1 with Table2.Field2 values in Database2 with an update query and inner join in Access? Both databases are in Access.

I read about the IN Clause (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907.aspx) but could not correctly implement it in an update query.

This code doesn't work but it gives the idea as to what I am looking to do:

```
 UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.ID IN "C:\Folder\Database.accdb"
SET Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field2
```

It doesn't work because Table 2 is in "C:\Folder\Database.accdb" but Table1 is in the database where I am running the update query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to work with the `IN` clause in updates. That way, it's explicit which table is in which database.

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 IN "C:\Folder\Database.accdb") t2 ON Table1.ID=t2.ID 
SET Table1.Field1 = t2.Field2
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to add a password? I've tried "PWD=password;C:\Folder\Database.accdb" and "MS Access;PWD=password;C:\Folder\Database.accdb" but both do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

Steps:
1. create linkedTable
2. run sql to update your table
3. delete linkedTable from point 1

```
Sub UpdateTAble()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim tbDef As DAO.TableDef

    'Create new table definition
    Set tbDef = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("Table2")

    'SourceTableName is a table name from soure db.
    tbDef.SourceTableName = "Table2"
    'Connect is full path to your source db.
    tbDef.Connect = "MS Access;DATABASE="C:\Folder\Database.accdb;"

    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tbDef
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh

    'Table2 is linked table but save in main DB - can be used without IN
    sql = "Update table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID = Table1.ID set table1.Field1 = table2.Field1"
    CurrentDb.Execute sql

    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "Table2"
End Sub
```